# Store value in DB with PHP - Ajax call from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

i want to store a value in a database with PHP. I call a PHP-function with AJAX.

I check on `document.ready()` if the website was called with a parameter called `temperature`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = 5; //gup('temperature', location.href);
    if(data != undefined){
        var sendData = 'func=storeValue&value=' + data + '&datetime=' + getDateTime();
        $.ajax({
            data: sendData,
            type: "POST",
            url: "FunctionManager.php",
            success: function(data){
                alert("Data Saved " + data);
            },
            error: function(xhr){
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I use a the php file "FunctionManager" to call the according function which i determine with the passed parameters. So i pass `data`and `datetime`. My FunctionManager looks like this:

```
    <?php
        include "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/SQLCommunication.php";

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        if(!isset($_GET['func']) && empty($_GET['func'])){
           exit();
        }

        if($_POST['func'] === "readValue"){
           echo readValue();
        }elseif($_POST['func'] === "storeValue"){
           echo storeValue($_POST["value"], $_POST["datetime"]);
        }
    ?>
```

So as you can see i first check which function is called and then call the function itself with parameters. I know that this works because i have a new row in my database after calling the website with a parameter. But the fields `datetime` and `value` are always zero.
My `storeValue`- function is located in `SQLCommunication.php`and looks like this:

```
function storeValue($val, $datetime){        
    $conn = establishConnection();
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error);
    }

    //$datetime = date_default_timezone_get();
    //$datetime = '2016-01-04 00:18:00';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tempvalues (datetime, value) VALUES ('$datetime', '$val')";
    $conn->query($sql);
    $conn->close();
}
```

This is the function i use to read the `temperature` parameter:

```
function gup( name, url ) {
  if (!url) url = location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( url ).toString();
  return results == null ? null : results[1];
}
```

Do you have any ideas which mistake i made?
Thanks

Comment: what is your database datatype for datetime?

Comment: It is `datetime`. And the datatpye of `value` is `INT`

Comment: i believe that when you do a jquery post, you can not send any get variables..

Comment: So should i change it to `GET`? No, it also does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery code must be like this. If you look at your browser console, you may see some errors.
The jquery should be like this:

```
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var day = date.getDate();
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var seconds = date.getSeconds();

newdate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

$(document).ready(function(){
    var storeValue = 'storeValue';
    var data = gup('temperature', location.href);        
    if(data != undefined){
    yourData = 'func='+storeValue+'&value='+data+'&newdate='+newdate;
        $.ajax({
            data: yourData,
            type: "POST",
            url: "FunctionManager.php,
            success: function(data){
                alert("Data Saved " + data);
            },
            error: function(xhr){
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In Functionmanager.php

```
    print_r($_POST);

    include "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/SQLCommunication.php";

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    if(!isset($_POST['func']) || empty($_POST['func'])){
       exit();
    }else{

 $func = isset($_POST['func'])? $_POST['func']: 'storeValue';
 $val = isset($_POST['value'])? $_POST['value']:'';
 $datetime = isset($_POST['newdate'])? $_POST['newdate']:'';

 if($func == 'readValue'){
        echo readValue();
 }elseif($func == 'storeValue'){
        echo storeValue($val, $datetime);
 }
}
```

In your date field in your table, set datatype as datetime. Hope this may help.

Comment: Doesn't work. I get nothing in my database now. I updated my code.

Comment: have you checked your console.

Comment: It says nothing. I only get a php error that the index `func`is not defined but that is a common php warning. The strange thing is that if i do `$_GET`instead of `$_POST` i don't get these warnings and also my `getData` function, which returns the latest value from the database, works again. So i don't know if it is right to stick with `$_POST`

Comment: So from where do you get `storeValue`. It's not included in your questions. var storeValue=$('#somethingmissing').val();

Comment: POST is still better if you are inserting data into database.

Comment: Oh, I look at your edited question, you don't need to use var in front of sendData. You don't use semi colon like I did in my answer as well

Comment: I added my `storeValue` function in question, it is loacted in `SQLCommunication.php` which i include.
Even if i remove `var`in front of `sendData` it still doesn't work. And i don't know why `POST`is better if it doesn't work?

Comment: The storeValue I am talking about is in the jquery. Anyway you can check each data send from ajax to php in the php file using print_r($_POST); You cannot use php variable storeValue inside the jquery script.

Comment: @binaryBigInt it is common to say a GET is used for a SELECT, and a POST is used for an INSERT or UPDATE...

Comment: `storeValue`is just a plain text. I tell my function in `FunctionManager`that i want to call the function `storeValue`from `SQLCommunication.php`
If i open `FunctionManager.php` manually with this url: `localhost/FunctionManager.php?func=storeValue&value=3&datetime=2015` i get a value in my database. So at least that works.

Comment: Look at the my updated code. Clear your browser cache and refresh as well.

Comment: `datetime` datatype should be datetime according to my answer.

Comment: Okay, so i just basically stored `storeValue` in a extra variable. This sadly still doesn't work :(

Comment: `does not work` does not help me figure your problem. please tell me the errors you are getting.

Comment: I just get `undefined index` in `FunctionManager`. How do i solve those notices?

Comment: I have updated my answer again. Check it. Just copy my code.

Comment: Okay, now i don't get these warnings anymore. But if i call `FunctionManager.php` manually with this URL `http://localhost/FunctionManager.php?func=storeValue&value=3&datetime=2016-01-04 00:18:00` everything works fine if i use `$_GET` but if i use `$_POST`(as you recommend) i get a new row in my table, but with just `0` instead of the actual values. I don't know why you say `$_POST` is better if it just doesn't work?

Comment: add print_r($_POST) at the top of your FunctionManager.php, open up your browser console, and under Network, see the response. And tell me what's in there. With GET user can inject malicious code in your database.

Comment: Looks like POST is fine with you. Have you check the response tab?

Comment: I don't get any response. The tab is empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107973/discussion-between-mawia-hl-and-binarybigint).